# Error 10022 returned by recvfrom() when multithreading (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, udp, pthreads

I'm new to socket programming and multithreading, I'm still learning it, but I have a problem that I can't solve, on some other topics I've found some answers but they don't look to have the same problem as me.

I would like to create a UDP client. This client should be able to send (`sendto()`) and receive (`recvfrom()`).

I'm multithreading the send and receive function, but the `recvfrom()` returns the error 10022 when I'm calling `WSAGetLastError()`.

I'm using the librairy `pthread.h` to multithread and `winsock2.h` for the socket.

When I'm not multithreading there is no problem.

My code:

```c
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

    #define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
    #define PORT 8888
    #define MAXBUFFER 1024

    void Sending(void *VarThread);
    void Receiving(void *VarThread);

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int sock;
        pthread_t Thread_ID_1;
        pthread_t Thread_ID_2;

        WSADATA WSAData;
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);


        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (sock == -1)
        {
            perror("\nsocket()");
            printf("%d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(0);
        }

        pthread_create(&Thread_ID_1, NULL, Sending, (void *)&sock);
        pthread_create(&Thread_ID_2, NULL, Receiving, (void *)&sock);

        pthread_join(Thread_ID_1, NULL);
        pthread_join(Thread_ID_2, NULL);

        close(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    void Sending(void *VarThread)
    {
        int sock = *(int *)VarThread;
        int i;

        struct sockaddr_in si;
        si.sin_family = AF_INET;
        si.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);
        si.sin_port = htons(PORT);

        char buff[MAXBUFFER];
        ssize_t message;

        while(1)
        {
            fgets(buff, MAXBUFFER, stdin);
            for(i = 1; i < MAXBUFFER; i++) // delete the last '\n'
            {
                if(buff[i] == '\0')
                {
                    buff[i - 1] = '\0';
                    i = MAXBUFFER;
                }
            }
            message = sendto(sock, buff, MAXBUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si, sizeof(si));
            if (message == -1)
            {
                perror("\nsendto()");
                printf("%d", WSAGetLastError());
            }
        }
    }


    void Receiving(void *VarThread)
    {
        int sock = *(int *)VarThread;
        char buff[MAXBUFFER];
        ssize_t recu;

        while(1)
        {
            recu = recvfrom(sock, buff, MAXBUFFER, 0, NULL, 0);
            if(recu == -1)
            {
                perror("\n\nError recvfrom ");
                printf("Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            }
            else
            {
                printf("message = %s\n", buff);
            }
        }
    }
```

(There is a pingpong server also running on my machine to test the code)

When I'm starting this app, the `recvfrom()` isn't blocking and return the error `10022` until I'm using the `Sending()` function. It's exactly when I'm using `fgets()` that `recvfrom()` stops to return the error.

How can I stop this error to happen?

P.S.: My machine is under Windows 10.

EDIT:

I've tried something else, I use `bind()` in the function `Receiving()` but it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
void *Receiving(void *VarThread)
{
    int sock = *(int *)VarThread;
    struct sockaddr_in SockRecv;
    int slen = sizeof(SockRecv);
    char buff[MAXBUFFER];
    ssize_t recu;




    memset((char *)&SockRecv, 0, sizeof(SockRecv));
    SockRecv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockRecv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(SERVER); 
    SockRecv.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&SockRecv, sizeof(SockRecv)) == -1)
    {
        perror("\n\nbind()");
        printf("Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }




    while(1)
    {
        recu = recvfrom(sock, buff, MAXBUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&SockRecv, &slen);
        if(recu == -1)
        {
            perror("\n\nError recvfrom()");
            printf("Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Message = %s\n", buff);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The proper function signature for a pthread function is `void *func(void*);` It is supposed to return a pointer.

Comment: I am not using UDP frequently but AFAIR to receive data sent for a specific port, you should bind the socket to that port first.

Comment: Error code [10022 is `EINVAL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/WinSock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) : "In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket"

Comment: Thank you @Gerhardh , I've changed the function to `void *func(void*);`.I just don't understand, where do you want to bind the socket if it's in the function so I will have to declare a `struct sockaddr_in` or if it's in the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 10022 is `WSAEINVAL`. [The microsoft documentation of recvfrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom) specifies what it means when it is caused by that function (emphasis mine):

> **The socket has not been bound with bind**, or an unknown flag was specified, 
>   or MSG_OOB was specified for a socket with SO_OOBINLINE enabled, or
>   (for byte stream-style sockets only) len was zero or negative.

Your attempt to bind it in the second code fragment has a different problem. You should bind the socket before starting either of the threads to avoid a race condition between the bind in the receive thread and the implicit bind that is part of the send.

Although you don't specify clearly how your use of bind fails, my guess is that adding the bind code delayed the receiver long enough to let the sender bind first, after which the receiver's bind fails because you cannot bind a socket twice.

Comment: I've edited my code and now it's working but I should bind in the main before anything else ?

Comment: After creating the socket obviously and before either thread is spawned. You say it's working now? Where did you put the bind?

Comment: Okay, yes it's working but I've put my bind in the `Receiving()` function

Comment: What did you change to make it work? There is still a chance that the send comes before the bind and I think that would cause a problem. Try adding a call to sleep 1 second at the start of the receive function and see what happens.

Comment: I've added the `Sleep(1000);` and if I'm sending something before the end of the timer it fails but if I'm waiting 1sec it works normally. (I've posted my code)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Because the send might occur before the receive has done the bind, the receive's bind may fail. This will not happen if you call bind before either thread has been started.

Comment: I just have one more question that might be stupid for you, how should I do to make two computers -that are not connected to the same router- communicate?

Comment: If you mean two computers both connected to the internet through a router, then the answer is port forwarding. A router will forward incoming traffic on a forwarded port to a specified port on a specified machine on the LAN. You only need to do port forwarding on the side of the server; the client's router will have seen the outgoing traffic that initiated the connection and automatically send through the return traffic from the server.

Comment: I adapted my answer to address both the problem in the original code fragment as well as the race condition in the second. If you think it sufficiently answers your question, please accept it. If not, let me know what else I can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Receiving Function

```c
void *Receiving(void *VarThread)
{
    int sock = *(int *)VarThread;
    struct sockaddr_in AddrRecv;
    struct sockaddr_in AddrSend;
    int LenAddrSend = sizeof(AddrSend);
    char buff[MAXBUFFER];
    ssize_t recu;

    memset((char *)&AddrRecv, 0, sizeof(AddrRecv));
    AddrRecv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    AddrRecv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); //inet_addr(SERVER);
    AddrRecv.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&AddrRecv, sizeof(AddrRecv)) != 0)
    {
        perror("\n\nbind()");
        printf("Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }




    while(1)
    {
        recu = recvfrom(sock, buff, MAXBUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&AddrSend, &LenAddrSend);
        if(recu == -1)
        {
            perror("\n\nError recvfrom()");
            printf("Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Message = %s\n", buff);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code, thanks to @Griffon26 and @Gerhardh

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 8888
#define MAXBUFFER 1024

void *Sending(void *VarThread);
void *Receiving(void *VarThread);

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    int sock;
    int i;

    pthread_t Thread_ID_1;
    pthread_t Thread_ID_2;

    WSADATA WSAData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);


    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        perror("\nsocket()");
        printf("%d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }


    struct sockaddr_in AddrRecv;

    memset((char *)&AddrRecv, 0, sizeof(AddrRecv));
    AddrRecv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    AddrRecv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    AddrRecv.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&AddrRecv, sizeof(AddrRecv)) != 0)
    {
        perror("\n\nbind()");
        printf("Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }


    pthread_create(&Thread_ID_1, NULL, Sending, (void *)&sock);
    pthread_create(&Thread_ID_2, NULL, Receiving, (void *)&sock);

    pthread_join(Thread_ID_1, NULL);
    pthread_join(Thread_ID_2, NULL);

    close(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

void *Sending(void *VarThread)
{
    int sock = *(int *)VarThread;
    int i;

    struct sockaddr_in si;
    si.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);
    si.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    char buff[MAXBUFFER];
    ssize_t message;

    while(1)
    {
        fgets(buff, MAXBUFFER, stdin);
        for(i = 1; i < MAXBUFFER; i++)
        {
            if(buff[i] == '\0')
            {
                buff[i - 1] = '\0';
                i = MAXBUFFER;
            }
        }
        message = sendto(sock, buff, MAXBUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si, sizeof(si));
        if (message == -1)
        {
            perror("\nsendto()");
            printf("%d", WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }
}


void *Receiving(void *VarThread)
{
    int sock = *(int *)VarThread;
    struct sockaddr_in AddrSend;
    int LenAddrSend = sizeof(AddrSend);
    char buff[MAXBUFFER];
    ssize_t recu;

    while(1)
    {
        recu = recvfrom(sock, buff, MAXBUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&AddrSend, &LenAddrSend);
        if(recu == -1)
        {
            perror("\n\nError recvfrom()");
            printf("Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Message = %s\n", buff);
        }
    }
}
```